# DataFrame from dict of lists with column values being keys

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Suppose we have the following dict:

```
things = {'George':['cat','kitty'], 'Stackoverflow':['questions','answers'], 'hungry':['im','always']}
```

One could easily turn this into a list containing `[[key1,value1]...[keyX,valueX]]` and turn this into a dataframe that appears as: (index and column names ignored here)

```
George          cat 
George          kitty
Stackoverflow   questions 
Stackoverflow   answers
hungry          im
hungry          always
```

However, is this possible to be one directly from a dictionary?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow your goal. Would `pd.DataFrame(things).stack().reset_index()` suffice?

Comment: hmm yeah, seeing the asnwers below =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [**`melt`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html#pandas.DataFrame.melt)

```
pd.DataFrame(things).melt()

        variable      value
0         George        cat
1         George      kitty
2  Stackoverflow  questions
3  Stackoverflow    answers
4         hungry         im
5         hungry     always
```

If you want column names here, just use the **`var_name`** and **`value_name`** flags:

```
pd.DataFrame(things).melt(var_name='foo', value_name='bar')
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this using [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html), and [`.stack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(things, orient='index').stack().reset_index(level=0)

         level_0          0
0         George        cat
1         George      kitty
2  Stackoverflow  questions
3  Stackoverflow    answers
4         hungry         im
5         hungry     always
```